# SP 2010 patch - when will it end

Tags: patching, support

Is it true that SP 2010 Patch will be ending October 13th, 2020?  if not, what's the correct date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is no longer ending on that original date it has been extened 6 months.

April 13, 2021 is the new date for end of support.

https://redmondmag.com/articles/2020/04/15/microsoft-extends-support-6-months.aspx

Or the official details from Microsoft - https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/lifecycle/search?alpha=SharePoint%20Server%202010

Comment: Thank you so much.